# Doubt in Inverse Trigonometric Function Problem

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

> **Question:** $\DeclareMathOperator{\cosec}{cosec}$
>
> Let domain and range of $\cosec^{-1}(x)$ be $(-\infty,-1]\bigcup[1,\infty)$ and $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]-\{\pi\}$. If $x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, then $\cosec^{-1}(\cosec(x))$ is
>
> (A) $2\pi-x$
>
> (B) $\pi+x$
>
> (C) $\pi-x$
>
> (D) $-\pi-x$

When the domain and range are principal, I used to convert the given domain or range to the principal by adding or subtracting $n\pi$. But, I tried here the same thing but I got the answer as D which is incorrect. Kindly help me solve this problem. I don't know any other method. Please explain.

Comment: If you look closely, options A,D can't be true because $-\pi-x\in(-3\pi/2,-\pi/2)$ and $2\pi-x\in(3\pi/2,5\pi/2)$, which don't intersect with the range given in the question. As for the answer, it would suffice to choose $x=\pi/4$ or some other convenient value and see where it gets mapped.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, But I wish to solve it not from options. Please guide me how to solve by not considering the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must have $y \in \bigg[\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\bigg] -\{\pi\}$ to obtain $\csc^{-1}(\csc y) = y$

Now $-\frac\pi2\lt x\lt \frac\pi2 \implies -\frac\pi2\lt- x\lt \frac\pi2 \implies \color{red}{\frac\pi2<-x+\pi<\frac{3\pi}2} \ x\ne0$

As, $\csc(\pi-x) = \csc(x)$

> $$\csc^{-1}(\csc(x)) = \csc^{-1}(\csc(\pi-x)) = \pi-x \ , \pi-x\in\bigg(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\bigg)-\{\pi\}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why did you multiply by -1 before adding $\pi$?

Comment: We could have just added $\pi$ without multiplying by -1 right?

Comment: It's just an intuition. We know that $\csc(\pi+x) = -\csc(x)$ which we don't require. So we have to go with the  other way.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if we do the other way?

Comment: Well, we'll then have $\csc(\pi+x) = -\csc(x) \implies \csc(x) = \csc(-\pi-x)$ which doesn't lie in the required range. So again we need to use the formula $\csc(\pi-y) = \csc(y)$ and finally reach the same place. So it's unnecessary.